# MacBook Pro remote connection

Tags: terminal, network, remote-desktop

I bought my MacBook Pro new in the packaging late 2019.
how do I see if it is being remotely connected to?
the reason im asking is I have some folders that are locked on here and in the activity monitor under network it has Remote /usr/libexec/remoted?
nobody should be connecting to the laptop
can I check under terminal a command to see who is connecting to my laptop?

Comment: under activity monitor it said remoted (72)

Comment: Are you asking about VNC?  As in Apple's Screen Sharing app?  That should show as an icon in the menu bar at the top of your screen.  File sharing (AFP or SMB) and remote login (SSH) should show somewhere else that I don't recall right now.  Maybe in Activity Monitor app somehow.